# TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\UnitTestCase can't be loaded in extbase unit test files

Tags: php, phpunit, typo3, extbase

I'm doing a standalone unit testing with phpunit for an extbase extension.

here is my phpunt.xml located in typo3conf/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./ext/test_extension/Tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

my folder structure is shown below

[image]

And the DummyControllerTest file is here

```
<?php
namespace Ricky\TestExtension\Tests\Unit\Controller;
/***************************************************************
 *  Copyright notice
 *
 *  (c) 2016 Ricky Mathew <ricky.mk@pitsolutions.com>, Pits
 *              
 *  All rights reserved
 *
 *  This script is part of the TYPO3 project. The TYPO3 project is
 *  free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  The GNU General Public License can be found at
 *  http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html.
 *
 *  This script is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  This copyright notice MUST APPEAR in all copies of the script!
 ***************************************************************/

/**
 * Test case for class Ricky\TestExtension\Controller\DummyController.
 *
 * @author Ricky Mathew <ricky.mk@pitsolutions.com>
 */
class DummyControllerTest extends \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\UnitTestCase
{

    /**
     * @var \Ricky\TestExtension\Controller\DummyController
     */
    protected $subject = NULL;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->subject = $this->getMock('Ricky\\TestExtension\\Controller\\DummyController', array('redirect', 'forward', 'addFlashMessage'), array(), '', FALSE);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        unset($this->subject);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function listActionFetchesAllDummiesFromRepositoryAndAssignsThemToView()
    {

        $allDummies = $this->getMock('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\ObjectStorage', array(), array(), '', FALSE);

        $dummyRepository = $this->getMock('Ricky\\TestExtension\\Domain\\Repository\\DummyRepository', array('findAll'), array(), '', FALSE);
        $dummyRepository->expects($this->once())->method('findAll')->will($this->returnValue($allDummies));
        $this->inject($this->subject, 'dummyRepository', $dummyRepository);

        $view = $this->getMock('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\View\\ViewInterface');
        $view->expects($this->once())->method('assign')->with('dummies', $allDummies);
        $this->inject($this->subject, 'view', $view);

        $this->subject->listAction();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function showActionAssignsTheGivenDummyToView()
    {
        $dummy = new \Ricky\TestExtension\Domain\Model\Dummy();

        $view = $this->getMock('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\View\\ViewInterface');
        $this->inject($this->subject, 'view', $view);
        $view->expects($this->once())->method('assign')->with('dummy', $dummy);

        $this->subject->showAction($dummy);
    }
}
```

But on running phpunit via commandline it throws

> Fatal error: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\UnitTestCase' not found in
>   /opt/xampp/htdocs/typo3testpro/typo3conf/ext/test_extension/Tests/Unit/Controller/DummyControllerTest.php
>   on line 37

Why it isn't autoloading?I tried to instantiate `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\UnitTestCase` inside my controller class just for testing and it is autoloading there perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bootstrap autoloading in PHPUnit (not only for TYPO3). To do so, add the attribute `bootstrap` to you `<phpunit>` element in the configuration file. It's a path to a file which is executed before the tests, and it should set up autoloading.

In TYPO3 context, you can use the file `typo3/sysext/core/Build/UnitTestsBootstrap.php`, it is provided by the TYPO3 core.

If you are running a project without TYPO3, you usually need to include the composer generated autoload file, by default it's the file `vendor/autoload.php`.

Your config file should look like this afterwards:

```
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    bootstrap="../typo3/sysext/core/Build/UnitTestsBootstrap.php"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./ext/test_extension/Tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I followed what u said.. then i got the following message in commandline

"Unable to determine path to entry script. Please check your path or set an environment variable 'TYPO3_PATH_WEB' "

@Jost

Comment: No idea why that happens, that setup works in my TYPO3 instances - what are you doing in your tests? Are they unit tests, or do they more things?

Comment: @RickyMathew I've had a same issue, running functional tests in composer-enabled TYPO3 with `web-dir` defined and `typo3-console` extension loaded. Fixed it by simply overloading `TYPO3_PATH_WEB` to point to root of installation - not to real web path (defined by `web-dir`) during tests execution like this: `TYPO3_PATH_WEB=/home/my_project ./bin/phpunit -c FunctionalTests.xml`